# Is it possible to use 1 IP address to RDP into different machines?

Tags: routing, rdp

We have 5 static public IP addresses. But we have a number of machines that we want to RDP into from home (our individual work pcs, a couple of servers, etc). Is there away to setup our router so that we can use 1 up address and route the RDP request to different machines based on port or something?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could also setup a Terminal Server Gateway. It only needs 1 open port (443, aka HTTPS), requires users to authenticate to it before letting anyone know what machines are on/available or what software they might be running. This of course requires a server that supports Terminal Server Gateway (Server 2003, 2008, etc).

Comment: +1 - that is exactly the professional solution. VERY nice, i use it all the time.

Comment: Does that allow me to connect to windows 7 machines on the network or only servers?

Comment: Almost any RDP Server can be connected to. I have personally used Windows 2000, XP, Vista, 7, Server 2003, 2008/R2. I've been told it also works for xRDP, but I haven't tried it myself. For the older OSes, you can't use NLA, just a configuration checkbox that needs to be unchecked.

Comment: BTW, I got this up and running and it's awesome! Thanks for the suggestion. I wish I could upvote this answer more than once.

Answer (score 7):

Sure you can! You need to change the RDP port on each machine, and port forward different ports to different computers.

To change the port number RDP listens on, edit the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\TerminalServer\WinStations\RDP-Tcp\PortNumber` on each machine.

Comment: So I coulnd't set it up like this: 67.197.8.192:151 -> 192.168.151:3349 (default RDP port)?

Comment: Based on the source port? It's unlikely, but some routers might allow it.

Comment: I think I get what you're saying. Basically with port forwarding i can only route to a different IP using the same port as the original request came in on. Correct?

Comment: -1... for ignoring remote services gateway which allows exactly that without port changes.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Some routers will allow a connection on an external port to be forwarded to a different internal port (Thomson Speedtouches jump to mind), but not many. What is your router?

Answer (score 4):

An easy way is to have the firewall/router port forward various ports to different target machines. No fiddling with Windows ports or having to use a TS Gateway.